# ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm

Tags: java, maven, jwt, java-module

I use the java-jwt (com.auth0:java-jwt:3.9.0) but I get a ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm. Do I have to include certain extra maven modules to my project? If so which ones and how can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I downloaded a copy of the JAR file for "com.auth0:java-jwt:3.9.0" from Maven Central, the `Algorithm` class that you are apparently missing *is in the JAR file*!

You can open the copy of the JAR file in your "~/.m2" repository and check for yourself that the class is present.  (You could also download the file from https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.9.0/jar and compare it with the copy that you have.)

Assuming that I am right, check that you included the JAR in the runtime classpath of your application OR that Maven has included it in the WAR / shaded JAR / whatever that you are deploying / running.